# I can't read the pg_auth_members table from the authentication hook in PSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, psql

At the authentication stage, I'm trying to get a list of roles that belong to the same group as the logged-in user. To do this, I used the system cache search functions, but for some reason using the `AUTHMEMROLEMEM` syscache id I get the error `" can't read pg_class without selecting the database (relcache.c:320)"`. If I use `AUTHMEMMEMROLE`, the search is performed normally. Based on the code, both IDs must refer to the same tables, for which the relisshare flag is set, and they must be available before authentication.

For example, the code in the hook that will cause the error:

```
HeapTuple       role_tup;
role_tup =  SearchSysCache2(AUTHMEMROLEMEM, ObjectIdGetDatum(user_oid), ObjectIdGetDatum(search_oid));
```

And which will not cause:

```
HeapTuple       role_tup;
role_tup =  SearchSysCache2(AUTHMEMMEMROLE,ObjectIdGetDatum(user_oid), ObjectIdGetDatum(search_oid));
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This index is not considered vital for authentication. See the following code in `RelationCacheInitializePhase3`:

```c
    /*
     * Process critical shared indexes too.
     *
     * DatabaseNameIndexId isn't critical for relcache loading, but rather for
     * initial lookup of MyDatabaseId, without which we'll never find any
     * non-shared catalogs at all.  Autovacuum calls InitPostgres with a
     * database OID, so it instead depends on DatabaseOidIndexId.  We also
     * need to nail up some indexes on pg_authid and pg_auth_members for use
     * during client authentication.  SharedSecLabelObjectIndexId isn't
     * critical for the core system, but authentication hooks might be
     * interested in it.
     */
    if (!criticalSharedRelcachesBuilt)
    {
        load_critical_index(DatabaseNameIndexId,
                            DatabaseRelationId);
        load_critical_index(DatabaseOidIndexId,
                            DatabaseRelationId);
        load_critical_index(AuthIdRolnameIndexId,
                            AuthIdRelationId);
        load_critical_index(AuthIdOidIndexId,
                            AuthIdRelationId);
        load_critical_index(AuthMemMemRoleIndexId,
                            AuthMemRelationId);
        load_critical_index(SharedSecLabelObjectIndexId,
                            SharedSecLabelRelationId);
```